# Acer AOD270 laptop with Linux Mint connected to Sharp LED TV, display exceeds screen

Tags: linux, laptop, linux-mint, hdmi

I am new to Linux Mint (Cinnamon) and got it installed on an Acer AOD270 netbook, but the built in display is already broken. So I have it connected via HDMI to a 32" Sharp LED TV, nothing fancy. I can see the display, but the edges of the display go beyond the four edges of the screen. My problem is I can't see the top of the windows (when they are maximized), the panel bar at the bottom, the menu on the left, or the scrollbar on the right.

I already looked around, changed resolution (from 1280x720), even tried xrandr command but nothing helped. Can anyone tell me how to resize my display to a ratio where I can see the edges? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "overscan" and is a feature of many TVs. The ideal way to solve this is via your TV's settings. For Sharp I believe you are looking for "dot-by-dot" or "fullscreen" mode.